# Best practice in sending message in python telegram bot from a 3d party listener

Tags: python, events, callback, python-telegram-bot, apscheduler

I have a custom code that does its routine and I want to send a message to myself in Telegram if something goes wrong. In my case I use `python-telegram-bot` library along with `apscheduler` and its listeners, where certain events could be catched.
I came up with such working code, but my question is: is it possible to make it better, namely without using global variable? This was done to overcome the problem that listeners do not accept arguments needed for bot to send a message.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.events import EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED, EVENT_JOB_ERROR
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
import copy
import my_custom_library

saved_update = None

def my_listener(event): # not related with bot
    if event.exception:
        if saved_update is not None:
            alert(saved_update, 'Scheduler threw event.exception.') # should have bot related args
    else:
        record = event.retval # get returned value from my_custom_library.repetitive_function
        try:
            processed_record = my_custom_library.my_unsafe_business_logic(record) # something might go wrong here
            my_custom_library.add_to_db(processed_record) # and here
        except Exception as e:
            if saved_update is not None:
                alert(saved_update, e) # should have bot related args

def start(update, context):
    global saved_update
    saved_update = copy.deepcopy(update) # this is what I don't like
    update.message.reply_text('You have subscribed for notifications.')

def alert(update, reason):
    update.message.reply_text('Something went wrong: {}'.format(reason))

def main():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_listener(my_listener, EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED | EVENT_JOB_ERROR)
    scheduler.add_job(my_custom_library.repetitive_function, args=(my_args,), trigger='interval', minutes=1)
    scheduler.start()

    # bot
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", callback=start))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I see you're trying to send `alert` message when there's an exception during runtime, so you're saving the `update` object. You can do, `context.bot.send_message(chat_id=yours)` and send the error message, so you don't have to save `update`. Other thing you can do is, `python-telegram-bot`'s `error_handler`, this will be called automatically when an exception occurs anywhere in program.

Comment: @GaganTK Unfortunately you can't use `context.bot.send_message` since it doesn't exist in custom listener.

Comment: right! Best thing you can do is, use `error_handler`, this triggers when an exception occurs in program

Answer (score 1):

The Telegram Bot API is fairly simple, you just ned to send an HTTP GET Request to this URL:
https://api.telegram.org/bot_token_/sendMessage?chat_id=123&text=Hello%20World!

Just create a bot with Botfather and send the Bot a message.
With the specified Token from Botfather and this URL:
https://api.telegram.org/bot_token_/getUpdates

You can get the messages which were sent to the Bot and the chat_id.

The simplest way would be to use the requests module and send the output of the updater to the first URL as the text parameter.

Comment: My question is more about best practices in coupling 2 different callbacks with different signatures. Your solution is not using `python-telegram-bot` at all, while I use some features which are not shown in a simplified original post.

Answer (score 0):

In my scripts I often use callbacks. It's a clean solution that provides separation between the two scripts. The send_message function can accept kwargs, so you can essentially create a dictionary, and update it when sending the message. The first part (channel ID) is something you know on the bot-side, and the second part (the text itself) is something you know one the third-party side.

In your third-party, provide a set_cb function that accepts a callback and a dictionary. Like so:

```
def set_cb(self, callback, params):
    self.callback = callback
    self.callback_params = params
```

In your bot script, set the callback before `updater.idle()`

```
# Start the Bot
updater = Updater("TOKEN")
updater.start_polling()

# Set the callback
r.set_cb(updater.bot.send_message, {"chat_id": 123456})
```

Then, in your third-party, once you want to send a message, simply add the message text call the following:

```
self.callback_params.update({"text": text})
self.callback(**self.callback_params) # converts the dict to kwargs
```